# How use django with decouple

Tags: python, django, python-decouple

I am trying to use python-decouple for sensitive data in my project but
When i use decouple.config for SECRET_KEY it raises an error

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/admin/Legaland/src/sqh/settings/dev.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._base import *
  File "/home/admin/Legaland/src/sqh/settings/_base.py", line 40, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = config("SECRET_KEY")
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 199, in __call__
    return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 83, in __call__
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 65, in get
    value = self.repository[option]
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 113, in __getitem__
    return self.parser.get(self.SECTION, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 800, in get
    d)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 394, in before_get
    self._interpolate_some(parser, option, L, value, section, defaults, 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 444, in _interpolate_some
    "found: %r" % (rest,))
configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found: '%^e=(r2l0*73)4zxv!(!4x(%(_koxr049zlesn3"'
```

How shall i make it read SECRET_KEY as text

```
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config("SECRET_KEY")
```

I am already I using .ini file for my email address and password the problem is that it tries  to perform SECRET_KEY instead of accepting it as a raw text  how can i prevent it

Comment: If possible then can you share your .env file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right to the point, as said by Henrique Bastos, [here](https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple#where-is-the-settings-data-stored):

> Note: Since ConfigParser supports string interpolation, to represent the character % you need to escape it as %%.

To use python-decouple with a *.ini* file you can do this:
Use your variable like said in the first answer:

```py
SECRET_KEY = config(SECRET_KEY, default='some-random-text')
```

You can use cast, if needed, like:

```py
DEBUG = config(DEBUG, default=True, cast=bool)# in the .ini file, the DEBUG value can be: 0, 1, True, False...
```

**So for last, your traceback error show that there is a percent sign in your .ini string value, you may need to do a scape with a %% as said in the official documentation** https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple

Do a escape parser with double percents, instead just one and the error will be gone!

Answer (score 1):

you should have a env file like below

.env

```
SECRET_KEY='aaassskkkk'
```

and then source your .env file using below command

```
source .env
```

then try the below code it will works

```
from decouple import config
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY', '')
```

if the SECRET_KEY not found in env it will take as ''

Comment: Thanks for your time already I using .ini file for my email address and password the problem is that it tries to perform SECRET_KEY instead of accepting it as a raw text how can i prevent it

Answer (score 1):

Decouple supports `.ini` and `.env` files. For use .env file simply create a `.env` text file in your repository's root directory.

```
SECRET_KEY='super-secret-key'
```

you can also override the parameter

```
SECRET_KEY='other-secret-key' python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Thanks for your time already I using .ini file for my email address and password the problem is that it tries  to perform SECRET_KEY instead of accepting it as a raw text  how can i prevent it